# Delete and insert records in the Spark DataFrame using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe called `original_df` with a variable number of columns and two other dataframes `delete_df` and `insert_df`.

```
original_df = 
+---+----+----+---+
|  s|  p1|  p2| p3|
+---+----+----+---+
| s1|  o1|  o2| o7|
| s1|  o2|  o2| o7|
| s2|  o3|null| o4|
| s3|null|  o5| o6|
| s4|null|null| o6|
+---+----+----+---+

delete_df =
+---+---+---+
|  s|  p|  o|
+---+---+---+
| s1| p3| o7|
| s2| p1| o3|
| s4| p3| o6|
+---+---+---+

insert_df = 
+---+---+---+
|  s|  p|  o|
+---+---+---+
| s1| p3| o8|
| s5| p2| o9|
+---+---+---+

final_df = 
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|  o8|
| s1|  o2|  o2|  o8|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
| s5|null|  o9|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

If a tuple `(s, o)` for a particular `p` of `delete_df` belongs to `(s, P)` of `original_df`, where `P` can be `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, etc. (`P` is variable; it can have any number of columns.) then the value of column `P` in the `final_df` for the particular `s` will be `null`.

Example: The `final_df` has a tuple `(s2, null, null, o4)` due to the `delete_df` having a tuple `(s2, p1, o3)`.

```
+---+----+----+---+
|  s|  p1|  p2| p3|
+---+----+----+---+
| s1|  o1|  o2| o7|
| s1|  o2|  o2| o7|
| s2|null|null| o4|
| s3|null|  o5| o6|
| s4|null|null| o6|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Similarly, we'll get the below df for the `(s1, p3, o7)` and `(s4, p3, o6)` tuples of the `delete_df`.

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|null|
| s1|  o2|  o2|null|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
| s4|null|null|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

We also have to remove records from the `final_df` if all columns `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, etc. have `null` values for a particular `s` value.

Example: We had `(s4, null, null, null)` in the `final_df` due to `(s4, p3, o6)` in the `delete_df`. We'll discard this record from the `final_df` because all the `P` columns have `null` values.

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|null|
| s1|  o2|  o2|null|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
+---+----+----+----+
```

The `insert_df` will be used to insert records into the `final_df`.
Example: We'll get the below df for the tuple `(s1, p3, o8)` of the `insert_df`.

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|  o8|
| s1|  o2|  o2|  o8|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Please let me know how efficiently I can achieve the `final_df` from the `original_df` using `delete_df` and `insert_df` in Scala.

Comment: How many lines can `delete_df` and `insert_df` have?

Comment: @Oli There is no limit on the number of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach very similar to the one I already proposed but that does not involve exploding `original_df`. Instead, we can group `insert_df` and `delete_df` by `s` and pivot over `p` so that they have the same structure as `original_df`. Then, we join on `s` and apply the logic you described in your question. At the end, we still need to remove the rows for which all p columns are null:

```scala
// the list of p columns
val P = original_df.columns.filter(_ startsWith "p")

val insert_pivot = insert_df
    .groupBy("s").pivot("p", P).agg(first('o))
    .select($"s" +: P.map(p => col(p) as s"insert_$p") : _* )
val delete_pivot = delete_df
    .groupBy("s").pivot("p", P).agg(first('o))
    .select($"s" +: P.map(p => col(p) as s"delete_$p") : _* )

// simply displaying insert_pivot to visualize the structure:
insert_pivot.show
```

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|  s|insert_p1|insert_p2|insert_p3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| s1|     null|     null|       o8|
| s5|     null|       o9|     null|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

```scala
original_df
    .join(delete_pivot, Seq("s"), "left")
    .select($"s" +: P.map(p => when( col(p) === col(s"delete_$p"), null).otherwise(col(p)) as p) : _*)
    .join(insert_pivot, Seq("s"), "full")
    .select($"s" +: P.map(p => coalesce(col(s"insert_$p"), col(p)) as p) : _* )
    .where(P.map(col).map(_.isNotNull).reduce(_||_))
    .show
```

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|  o8|
| s1|  o2|  o2|  o8|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
| s5|null|  o9|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

If `delete_df` and `insert_df` are small enough to be collected to the driver and used in `when` clauses, that's probably the most efficient way to go.

In the general case, if no such assumption can be made, I would propose to explode `original_df` as follows:

```
+---+---+----+
|  s|  p|   o|
+---+---+----+
| s1| p1|  o1|
| s1| p2|  o2|
| s1| p3|  o7|
| s1| p1|  o2|
| s1| p2|  o2|
| s1| p3|  o7|
| s2| p1|  o3|
| s2| p2|null|
| s2| p3|  o4|
| s3| p1|null|
| s3| p2|  o5|
| s3| p3|  o6|
| s4| p1|null|
| s4| p2|null|
| s4| p3|  o6|
+---+---+----+
```

And then join that exploded dataframe with `delete_df` on `[s,p,o]` to find out what needs to be deleted and with `insert_df` on `[s,p]` to insert what needs to be inserted. Then we can group by `s` and pivot over `p` to obtain the `final_df`

The code would go as follows:

```scala
// the list of p columns
val P = original_df.columns.filter(_ startsWith "p")

original_df
    .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
    .select($"s", 'id, explode(array(
        P.map(p => struct(lit(p).alias("p"), col(p).alias("o"))) : _*
    )) as "P" )
    .select('s, 'id, $"P.*")
    .join(delete_df.withColumn("delete", lit(true)), Seq("s", "p", "o"), "left")
    .withColumn("o", when('delete, null).otherwise('o))
    .join(insert_df.withColumnRenamed("o", "new_o"), Seq("s", "p"), "full")
    .withColumn("o", coalesce('new_o, 'o))
    .groupBy("id", "s").pivot("p").agg(first('o) as "o")
    // removing values for which all P columns are null
    .where(P.map(col).map(_.isNotNull).reduce(_||_)).orderBy("s", "id")
    .drop("id")
    .show
```

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|  o8|
| s1|  o2|  o2|  o8|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
| s5|null|  o9|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Since you can have duplicates in the `s` column, there is an additional subtlety. To be able to get all the rows back when pivoting, we need an unique row `id` to keep track of which values belong to which row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. Can we transform the dataframes delete_df and insert_df similar to original_df using groupby and pivot, and then apply the transformations to get the final_df? Can we avoid applying explode to the original_df?

Comment: I think it is possible. I am not sure this will improve the performance though if that was the question :). Exploding is not that expensive since it does not involve a shuffle and the data does not take much more space.
Let me add another answer. If you try both approaches with real datasets, I am curious to know if there is a performance difference.

Comment: I added the other answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the code in python!

Here you have another way to do it. It doesn't use `groupBy().pivot()`, but uses `Array` and `Map` operations like `array_except` and `array_union`.

```py
original_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("s1", "o1", "o2", "o7"),
  ("s1", "o2", "o2", "o7"),
  ("s2", "o3", None, "o4"),
  ("s3", None, "o5", "o6"),
  ("s4", None, None, "o6")],
  schema=["s", "p1", "p2", "p3"]
)

delete_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("s1", "p3", "o7"),
  ("s2", "p1", "o3"),
  ("s4", "p3", "o6")],
  schema=["s", "p", "o"]
)

insert_df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("s1", "p3", "o8"),
  ("s5", "p2", "o9")],
  schema=["s", "p", "o"]
)
```

```py
# array with all "" columns
p_arr = [F.struct(F.lit(col).name("p"), F.col(col).name("o")) for col in original_df.columns if col.startswith("p")]

original_arr = original_df.select("s", F.array(*p_arr).name("p_arr"))
delete_arr = delete_df.groupBy("s").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("p", "o")).name("delete_arr"))
insert_arr = insert_df.groupBy("s").agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("p", "o")).name("insert_arr"))
```

```py
original_map = original_arr \
  .withColumn("p_arr",  F.filter("p_arr", lambda e: e.getItem("o").isNotNull())) \
  .join(delete_arr, "s", how="left") \
  .join(insert_arr, "s", how="outer") \
  .withColumn("p_arr",  F.expr("IF (p_arr IS NULL, Array(), p_arr)")) \
  .withColumn("delete_arr", F.expr("IF (delete_arr IS NULL, Array(), delete_arr)")) \
  .withColumn("insert_arr", F.expr("IF (insert_arr IS NULL, Array(), insert_arr)")) \
  .withColumn("p_arr", F.array_except("p_arr", "delete_arr")) \
  .withColumn("p_arr", F.array_union("p_arr", "insert_arr")) \
  .withColumn("p_map", F.map_from_entries("p_arr")) \
  .filter(F.size("p_arr") > 0)
```

```py
# get all different keys
keys = original_map.select(F.explode(F.map_keys("p_map")).name("key")) \
  .distinct().orderBy("key").collect()
keys = [row.key for row in keys]

# unfold the map
original_map.select(
    "s",
    *[F.col("p_map").getItem(key).name(key) for key in keys]
).orderBy("s").show()
```

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  s|  p1|  p2|  p3|
+---+----+----+----+
| s1|  o1|  o2|  o8|
| s1|  o2|  o2|  o8|
| s2|null|null|  o4|
| s3|null|  o5|  o6|
| s5|null|  o9|null|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Oli's solution seems more clear and efficient, but I have spent too much time not to post my solution !

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort.